# How to pass query parameter in AngularJS 2?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, angular, http, asp.net-core

I am using ASP.NET Core and AngularJS 2. There is a problem with http query parameter. No matter what I try, parameter `'quarter'` is not passed to controller. Anyone have idea what ma I missing here ?

```
getBookingsBySaleUnit() {
    let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('quarter', '1');
    let requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
    requestOptions.search = params; 

    this.http.get('/api/method', requestOptions).subscribe(result => {
            this.sales = result.json();
        }
      );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
    let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('quarter', 1);
    this.http.get('Result/Delete', { search: params })
       .subscribe([...])
```

Comment: You are right BUT can't believe how simple it was. Actually I was calling controller so ALL I have to do is append it to the URL http.get('/api/method/' + this.quarter) :(

Answer (score 0):

You missed to pass the parameter. Try the code below which includes parameter in the URL.

```ts
getBookingsBySaleUnit() {
    let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append('quarter', '1');
    let requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
    requestOptions.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    this.http.get('/api/method?'+params.toString(), requestOptions).subscribe(result => {
        this.sales = result.json();
    });
}
```